# How to remove the TWM desktop environment?

Tags: launcher, desktop-environments

I found the user interface of the TWM desktop environment boring and hard to use. How can I remove it?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove twm`

Comment: These two TWM and Ubuntu(default)were installed by default

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get remove twm
```

This worked.